# How do I display a long number in groups?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, formatting

I have a string

```
string = '1234432198766789'
```

I want it to look like this:

```
"1234 4321 9876 6789"
```

What is the best way to do it? I am able to use Rails' String extensions.

I don't want to modify the original string, so `insert` method couldn't be used.

Comment: There needs to be a lot more information: Are the strings always the same length? Or, are they always even boundaries of four characters? Or, could they be arbitrary lengths and you want to break them into as many four-character chunks as possible? And, if the last is what you want, where should the overflow characters go, at the start or end of the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p '12345678'.reverse.scan(/.{1,4}/).join(' ').reverse
# => "1234 5678"
```

Why the double `reverse`?  So that when the string's length is not a multiple of four, the odd-sized group will be on the left:

```
p '123456'.reverse.scan(/.{1,4}/).join(' ').reverse
# => "12 3456"
```

If you know your string will always be a multiple of four, or if you don't mind the odd-sized group being on the right, then leave out the two calls to `reverse`.

```
p '123456'.scan(/.{1,4}/).join(' ')
# => "1234 56"
```

Comment: This was exactly where I was headed when I asked the OP for clarification on the need. You must have been bitten by similar issues of a field width varying unexpectedly too at some point. :-)

Comment: @Greg, Although I don't recall it, I'm sure you're right.  I must have learned the double-reverse idiom from somewhere. :)

Answer (score 4):

Long version:

```
string.split("").in_groups_of(4).map { |s| s.join("") }.join(" ")
```

Is this supposed to be a phone number of some sort? Rails has a [`number_to_phone` helper that you could use](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_phone).

Comment: Where is `in_groups_of()` documented? I don't see it in Array.

Comment: The pure Ruby way is to use `each_slice(4)`. The `in_groups_of` method is part of ActiveSupport, see: http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/Grouping.html

Comment: Greg: it's a Rails (Active Support) extension to the Array class that, for some reason, doesn't appear on api.rubyonrails.org

Comment: Ryan, Ah, I checked with ri and it didn't show up there so that's why I was confused.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
string.scan(/.{1,4}/).join(' ')
```

P.S. Ryan's solution has the benefit of possibly change `string.split('')` with `string.chars.to_a` if you ever have to do i18n stuff. It can be a nightmare...